# MSC Adams: “angular kinetic energy” vs “angular momentum about a center of mass”: which is the most relevant measure of the flywheel's storage?

Tags: simulation, flywheels

MSC Adams produces several different measures of a rotating body. In a flywheel, what is the difference between 'angular kinetic energy' (in newton-mm) vs 'angular momentum about the center of mass' (in newton-mm-sec), and which is the most relevant measure of the flywheel's storage, which is usually measured in Kinetic Energy (in Joules) as in http://www.calculatoredge.com/mech/flywheel.htm?

Bonus points: how would one compare results from MSC Adams and of the usual calculation (in the link above) to cross-verify each other?

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum $$L=I\omega$$, Is the rotational momentum of a flywheel or a rotating object and is the product of I with angular velocity. It is preserved by conservation of angular momentum law. It is analogous to linear momentum. For a disk $$L=\omega*1/2MR^2,\quad generally \ L=K^2M, \quad\text{K= radius of gyration}$$

It is a vector value.

Wikipedia figure of I of some objects.

[image: Wikipedia fig.]

.

But when the same flywheel or object actually turns with an angular velocity of $\omega$ then it has accumulated angular kinetic energy.

$$KE=1/2I\omega^2$$

This is a scaler value.